# Can you explain the following code for detection and removal of outliers?

Tags: self-study, matlab, outliers, naive-bayes

My teacher wrote this to detect and remove Outliers from a data set.

```
load train.txt
load test.txt

% comparing mean and median values
[mean(train); median(train)]

% You can compare here different parameters computed on train 
% and test sets - they should be roughly the same

% plot histogram - to check histogram plotting first show labels (1..4)
% we can use hist for just one dimension
hist(train(:,1))

% now plot histogram of the first feature
hist(train(:,2))

% plot 2-dimensional diagram of the first two features
% it's good to repeat plotting after each modification of the training set
plot2features(train, 2, 3);

% to find row in which outlier sits
[mv mi] = max(train)

% to remove outlier from the training set
train(186,:)=[];

% to find row in which outlier sits
[mv mi] = min(train)

% to remove outlier from the training set
train(641,:)=[];
```

I couldn't understand what he did and why he did that.

- How is he actually detecting Outliers?
- What does it mean by `[mean(train); median(train)]`?
- What does this `[mv mi] = min(train)` and this `[mv mi] = max(train)` code do?

Comment: @Xi'an, its not `aelf-study`. It is `self-study`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your teacher is eye-balling the outliers.

```
% print the index of an outlier, and memorize it
[mv mi] = max(train)

% he recalls that the max value was 186, and removes it 
train(186,:)=[];
```

It's an "interesting" way to deal with outliers, unusual too. He takes out min and max values.